# How can I get the information from the link and save it in a csv file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the information about a journalist form the link and save each variable(name, country, type of death, etc) as one column in a csv file. How can I do this? The link is https://cpj.org/data/people/abadullah-hananzai/index.php

Answer (score 0):

The site is using AJAX to load the data from different URL in JSON form. This can get you started:

```
import requests
from operator import itemgetter
import csv

data_url = 'https://cpj.org/api/datamanager/killed?source=http://cpj.org/data/people/abadullah_hananzai/'
data = [*zip(*map(itemgetter('tag', 'value'), requests.get(data_url).json()))]

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

Output of `out.csv`:

```
currentStatus,type,lastStatus,motiveConfirmed,fullName,localOrForeign,mediums,jobs,coverages,gender,employedAs,typeOfDeath,captive,sourcesOfFire,tortured,impunity,threatened,status,organizations,freelance,country,locality,date,subheading
Killed,Journalist,Killed,Confirmed,Abadullah Hananzai,Local,"Radio, Internet",Producer,"Crime, Politics, War",Male,Staff,Murder,No,Political Group,No,Complete Impunity,No,Killed,"Radio Azadi,Radio Free Europe/Radio Liberty",No,Afghanistan,Kabul,"April 30, 2018","Radio Azadi,Radio Free Europe/Radio Liberty | Killed in Kabul, Afghanistan | April 30, 2018"
```

In LibreOffice it looks like this:

[image]